# Make my android app appear in the share list of a specific app only

Tags: android

I want to restrict that my app should only be shown in the share list of specific apps .

This is my current solution: -

```
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
      </intent-filter>
```

This works perfectly but it displays my app in the share list of all apps . Any solution to display my app in the share list of only specific apps .

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://gist.github.com/drmercer/67302c7ccd2b4454fb07)

```
<!-- Accept text via ACTION_SEND only from the Github Android app ("com.github.mobile") -->
<intent-filter android:label="Share to MyApp">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

    <category android:name="com.github.mobile" />
    <!-- This ^ makes it only accept intents from package "com.github.mobile" -->

    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```